# Can a B-movie movie get promoted due to high rating from audience?

Tags: content-rating, reception

As I understand, a B-movie gets its rating prior to becoming publicly available. As a result (correct me if I am wrong), it is not yet known the true public rating of the movie at that time.

What I am wondering about is whether it is possible for a B-movie to get promoted to an A-movie movie due to its high popularity and critics rating?

Comment: Didn't this happen with *Dark Star*?

Comment: Um, are you sure a "B movie" is actually officially rated as a "B movie" rather than just being inofficially called that *by* the public? There is no actual rating board that says a movie is a "B movie". This question seems to be quite wrongly premised.

Answer (score 11):

The term "B movie", at least in modern movies, doesn't have any kind of official meaning. It's not a rating that gets applied to a movie by some organization, it's really just a "genre" of movie.

Originally, the term B-movie was used in much the same way as the B-side of a musical single record; the "B" movie was the "other half" of a double feature. The B movie was use as the lead in -- the same place we currently see trailers, for example -- and rarely got much promotion of its own. These days, double features are pretty rare, so the term almost never has this meaning.

Instead, it's typically used as a reflection on the budget the movie has. A B movie is a low-budget movie that is not an "art" film. The term isn't always meant as an insult -- sometimes B movies become very well known for taking risks or breaking movie conventions that high budget films would never dare. Just because a B movie becomes popular doesn't change the fact that it was filmed on a low budget, with all of the associated stylistic choices that come with it.

So no, there's not really any way for a B movie to "become" an A movie, any more than an action movie can "become" a horror; it's just a way to describe the way the movie was made.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about B-movies. If I am wrong please let me know.

"B" movies were:

> "...films that were made cheaply and quickly. They were used to fill the bottom half of a double bill when double features were standard."
>   *-History of Narrative Film*, *(Cook-third edition)*

Tarantino and Rodriguez have done some movies (such as *Grindhouse)* in the last few decades that are basically an homage to the "genre", but they are generally considered too well-connected and/or monied to be in the same class with Corman. Another example would be Asylum's *Transmorphers*, a so-called mockbuster.

Nowadays, about the closest thing we have to B-movies are fan-films created with a Nikon D5 (or similar) and posted on YouTube.

So, the B is due to billing, budget, and often, but not always, quality.